# Playground execution failed on Int() type conversion

Tags: ios, swift

I was working on this tutorial on Swift when I ran into this problem.

**code:**

```
var languagesLearned: String = "3"
if let num: Int? = Int(languagesLearned)
{
    print("It is a number")
}
else
{
    print("It is not a number")
}
```

**error:**

```
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/f7/0j8dbxls0kv0l9d6jwk30f2h0000gn/T/lldb/20598/playground134.swift:72:20: error: cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type '@lvalue String'
if let num: Int? = Int(languagesLearned)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can't find anything on why I'm getting this kind of error. I also have no idea what it's saying about init.

**Corrected Code After Answer**

```
var languagesLearned: String = "3"
var languagesLearnedNum = languagesLearned.toInt()
if let num = languagesLearnedNum
{
    print("It is a number")
}
else
{
    print("It is not a number")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 1.x, use:

```
languagesLearned.toInt()
```

Comment: Also, don't type the `num` variable as an optional int (`Int?`). It's no longer optional at that point.

Comment: Since I want to leave the final converted code (from Swift 2 to 1.x) for anyone else who stumbles across this problem, is `var languagesLearnedNum = languagesLearned.toInt()` correct or should you shorten the `if let` to `if let num = languagesLearned.toInt()`?

Comment: The second one is probably better, IMO.